# How to open an Office365 calendar event from its WebLink in edit mode

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

Whenever I try to open in a browser an Office365 calendar event using its WebLink received from the Outlook API it opens a page with only the title of the event and the date and time it was created at and I do not have the option to open it in edit mode or to see any other information about it.

I have also checked this issue on other browsers, incognito modes and different PCs or devices, the only difference I noticed was that for tablets or phones I also had two options (to delete or flag the event).

Until 2-3 weeks ago I had the possibility to open Events in edit mode so I'm not sure if something in the API changed or if it is a problem on my side related to settings/rights.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding, we are not able to get the edit link from the webLink which we get the events via the REST API for the security consideration since get events API only require read permission.

And what’s kind of information you want? If the event view page for the event didn’t show the information you want, as a workaround I suggest that you get these information using the Graph API.

Also you can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/313228--outlook-on-the-web-office-365) if you want that the other information display on the event view page.

Comment: I am not trying to open the event directly in edit mode. Previously, using the same WebLink, I could open an event (in read only mode) and on that page I could see the start and end times or the location and on the top of the page I would see a menu bar with an Edit option that would open the Event in edit mode. So this functionality was already present and I wanted to know if it was removed or if something changed.